# weak convergence in $c_0(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Let \begin{equation}X := c_0(\mathbb{N}), \hspace{3mm}x_0 \in X, \hspace{3mm}\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset X  \quad bounded\end{equation} . Show that

\begin{equation}
x_n \rightharpoonup x_0 \Longleftrightarrow x_n(k) \rightarrow x_0(k)
\end{equation}

I tried to solve the $\Longrightarrow$ part:

I know that
\begin{equation}
\forall \{y_k\}_k \in \ell^1(\mathbb{N}) \quad, \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_{n}(k)y(k) \rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_0(k)y(k) \quad as \hspace{2mm}n \rightarrow \infty
\end{equation} 
that means
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(x_{n}(k)-x_0(k))y(k) \rightarrow 0 \quad as \hspace{2mm}n \rightarrow \infty
\end{equation}

and the only possibility is that $x_n(k) \rightarrow x_0(k)$

I'm at a loss for the other implication. Any hints/help?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\psi_k$ denote the linear functional $\psi_k(x) := x(k)$. Then, under the isomorphism $\ell^1 \cong X^{\ast}$, $\psi_k$ corresponds to the element $e_k$, where $e_k = (0,0,\ldots, 1, 0, 0, \ldots)$. Use this to show that $E:= \text{span}\{\psi_k : k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in $X^{\ast}$.

Now you need the fact that $\{x_n\}$ is bounded, say by $M\geq 0$. Use this, together with the first paragraph to conclude that $\psi(x_n) \to \psi(x_0)$ for any $\psi \in X^{\ast}$ using the usual $\epsilon/3$ trick.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I think I get it, that span is dense because I can identify it with the orthonormal basis. Then I can say $|\psi(x_{n})-\psi(x_0)| \leqslant |\psi(x_{n})-\psi_{k}(x_{n})|+|\psi_{k}(x_{n})-\psi_{k}(x_{0})|+|\psi_{k}(x_{0})-\psi(x_{0})|$ the first one and the third one are less then $\varepsilon$/3 because of density, the second one because of the hypothesis. I don't understand where boundness comes into play.

Comment: would I be able to use a similar argument if I have the same request but $X=\ell^p$ (changing accordingly the isomorphism)? Any suggestions as to where find more about these topics? I feel like the course I'm taking is lacking